# Uploading an image using activityResultLauncher , convert URI into bitmap

Tags: java, android, bitmap, start-activity

I am very new to this, and I am trying to put the pieces together so I will get the result I want. I don't really understand what I am doing wrong. The problem is when I am trying to put a profile photo, by the time I am pressing the selected photo to show on image view, the app crashes and I got a message like "URI cannot be null".

```
public class Profile extends AppCompatActivity {

private ImageView ProfileImg;

private String Tag;

private Uri imagePath = null;

private Uri imageUriPath;

ProgressBar progressBar;




@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_profile);
    progressBar = findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
    Button btnUpload = findViewById(R.id.btnUploadPhoto);
    Button btnLogOut = findViewById(R.id.btnLogOut);
    ProfileImg = findViewById(R.id.profile_img);


    /* START ACTIVITY FOR RESULT*/



    btnLogOut.setOnClickListener(view -> {

        FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signOut();
        startActivity(new Intent(Profile.this,MainActivity.class).setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK|Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP));
        finish();

    });

    ProfileImg.setOnClickListener(view -> {

        Intent photoIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
        photoIntent.setType("image/*");
        NewStartActivityForResult.launch(photoIntent);

    });
    
    btnUpload.setOnClickListener(view -> {
        
        uploadImage();
        
    });



    /*Select photo from device*/


}

private ActivityResultLauncher<Intent> NewStartActivityForResult = registerForActivityResult(new ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult(), result -> {

    if (result.getResultCode() == Activity.RESULT_OK){

        Intent GotResults = result.getData();

        if(GotResults == null)
        {
            Log.d(Tag,"InitializedActivityLaunchers: intent data is null");
            return;
        }
        Uri imageUriPath = GotResults.getData();
        GetImageInView();
    }


});

private void uploadImage() {

    FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference("images/" + UUID.randomUUID().toString()).putFile(imagePath).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot> task) {
            if (task.isSuccessful())
            {
                Toast.makeText(Profile.this, "Image Uploaded!",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }else {
                Toast.makeText(Profile.this, "Something went Wrong!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    });

}

private void GetImageInView(){

    Bitmap bitmap = null;
    try{
        bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getContentResolver(),imageUriPath);
    }catch (IOException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

I first had a problem with startOnActivityResult in which I had a line through the command saying that is deprecated and MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap in which I had the same "error", deprecated on getBitmap, and I tried to use the new methods watching tutorials and other forums, but I think I cannot connect the activityResultLauncher with Bitmap because the output of activityResultLauncher is Intent and Bitmap needs URI.

Comment: when using activityResultLauncher  you can try something like this intent.getData().getPath()  (first check for null )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `NewStartActivityForResult` , just manage code as mentioned below

From

```
Uri imageUriPath = GotResults.getData();
```

To

```
imageUriPath = GotResults.getData();
```

You are declaring and initalising variable instead of only initalising